# How to add an Href to a button. (Tried solutions in post)

Tags: c#, datatable

I know this seems like something you would learn in your first week of programming. But could someone help me with the below? I have a sql statement to select my information from the DB. (I Use a string builder to build my table, the id is 'html'. Basically, whenever my table encounters my trip prefix id (primary key), it is supposed to add a button, along with the href to point to the edit page, as seen below.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    html.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<td>");
        if (column.ColumnName == Convert.ToString("Edit"))
        {
            html.Append("<button type = \"button\" href=TripPrefixAdministration.aspx?TripPrefixId=" + row[column.ColumnName] + "> Edit</button>");
        }

        else
       {
        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
       }
        html.Append("</td>");
    }
    html.Append("</tr>");
}
```

Please note this is only one portion of my table builder, and i have a adapter and a datatable to hold the information. (My error is that nothing happens when i click the button. There is no href it picks up)

Comment: Why don't you just use the `a href` tag and style it to look like a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons don't have hrefs.  If you still want to add a href attribute, do this:

```
html.Append("<button type = \"button\" href=\"TripPrefixAdministration.aspx?TripPrefixId=" + row[column.ColumnName] + "\"> Edit</button>");
```

A better way would be to use a regular hyperlink:

```
 html.Append("<a href=\"TripPrefixAdministration.aspx?TripPrefixId=" + row[column.ColumnName] + "\"> Edit</a>");
```

Then you could style it using CSS to make it look like a button.

Comment: Bless you kind sir. I never knew you couldnt use an href. But i will keep this in mind for the future. Thanks. Will accept answer just now.